# sparksession can't connect to hive in sparkstreaming operation

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

in my project,i want to use sparksession anlyze hive data after accepted spark streaming info.i can create a sparksession easily,but it use spark warehouse itself.the sparksession cant connect to hive metastore via my code passed.in my spark conf directory it exist hive-site.xml and has hive jars in spark jars.

```java
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> tablesinfo = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                javaStreamingContext,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topicsFromArgset, kafkaParams)
        );
tablesinfo.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

      if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
           SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton
                        .getInstance(rdd.context().getConf()
                         , prop.getProperty("metaUris"));
....
      }
}

class JavaSparkSessionSingleton {
    private static transient SparkSession instance = null;
    public static SparkSession getInstance(SparkConf sparkConf,String metaUri) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .config(sparkConf)
                    .config("hive.metastore.uris",metaUri)
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

isn't a allowed opration? or i have mistakes in code?
```

Comment: Why do you want to connect to hive? i mean what is your use case. If you want to store streaming data in hive table, then you cannot do it directly in spark streaming. you can use foreachbach to write your custom sink.